# adding validation(jquery and server side) to wtforms

Tags: jquery, python, google-app-engine, jinja2, wtforms

I have a simple model forms, that is being rendered through the following jinja2 template:

```
<form method="POST" action=""> 
    <table>
      {% for field in form %}   

      <tr>{{ field.label }}</tr>
      <tr>{{ field()|safe }}</tr>

      <tr>
        {% if field.errors %}
        <td>
          <ul class=errors>
            {% for error in field.errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </td>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" class="btn"  value="Submit Form"/>
  </form>
```

I wanted to customize the output of the wtforms and to each of the form fields being rendered, i wanted to add a class `"required"` to use a jquery client side validation plugin.

Following is my appengine db model:

```
class Song(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    lyrics = db.TextProperty()
    duration = db.IntegerProperty()
    movie = db.ReferenceProperty(Movie)
    singer = db.ReferenceProperty(Singer)
```

and following is my form, rendering script:

```
SubTaskForm = model_form(Song, 
                         exclude=('movie', 'singer'),
                         )
```

What would be a good way to attach validators using wtfroms validators, also how can i attach a **class=required** to the form fields?

Let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to override the stuff in python, where you define them, another thing that can be done is, you might try in the templates itself, `<tr class="required">`
Give it a try, should work.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this library https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WTForms-ParsleyJS Generate client side, parsley.js validation tags automatically from WTForms server side validators.

http://codevisually.com/parsley-js/
Parsley.js is a lightweight (12k minified) forms validation JavaScript library with a difference. Instead of validating the forms with JS it uses data attributes to achieve the same effect. It works with both jQuery and Zepto and it is very easy to configure, allowing you to override almost every Parsley default behavior to fit your exact needs.

Answer (score 0):

The renderer (field()) passes on arguments as attributes in the generated HTML. So, by calling, e.g., field(class='required') you can mark the field(s) as required and apply the jquery validate plugin as usual.  If your context treats 'class' as a keyword, you can pass in 'class_'.  Details in the **call** note for [WTForms.field](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html).

Comment: Remember class is _class with fields (class is reserved)